# Oozie cannot access metastore database in HUE

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, metastore

I'm on CDH4, in HUE, I have a database in Metastore Manager named db1.  I can run Hive queries that create objects in db1 with no problem.  I put those same queries in scripts and run them through Oozie and they fail with this message:

**FAILED: SemanticException 0:0 Error creating temporary folder on: hdfs://lad1dithd1002.thehartford.com:8020/appl/hive/warehouse/db1.db. Error encountered near token 'TOK_TMP_FILE'**

I created db1 in the Metastore Manager as HUE user db1, and as HUE user admin, and as HUE user db1, and nothing works.  The db1 user also has a db1 ID on the underlying Linux cluster, if that helps.

I have chmod'd the /appl/hive/warehouse/db1.db to read, write, execute to owner, group, other, and none of that makes a difference.

I'm almost certain it's a rights issue, but what?  Oddly, I have this working under another ID where I had hacked some combination of things that seemed to have worked, but I'm not sure how.  It was all in HUE, so if possible, I'd like a solution doable in HUE so I can easily hand it off to folks who prefer to work at the GUI level.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you chmod to 1777?

Comment: I tried 777 in a few places, but not 1777.  I think of not setting the sticky bit as an even looser form of security, so I'm assuming 777 is the same.  Is there some magic to the sticky bit?

Comment: Also, chmod what?  The db1.db folder?  The "warehouse" folder is already 1777, I believe by default, but at least that's what it is now in our system.  I'll try it now and let you know.

Comment: Did a chmod 1777 on the db1.db folder.  Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add hive-site.xml into your Files and Job XML fields? Hue has great tutorial about how to run Hive job. Watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu1IM4rph6w). Adding of hive-site.xml is described around 4:20.

Comment: Yes.  That video is how I knew to do it, it's a great one.  But yes, those are in place in each action.  I've also tried adding it as a property at the Workflow level itself, but same results.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same error on Hadoop MapR.
Root cause : Main database and temporary(scrat) database were created by different users.
Resolution : Creating both folders with same ID might help with this.